# Disadvantages of Lazy<T>?

Tags: c#, mef

I recently started using [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) throughout my application, and I was wondering if there are any obvious negative aspects that I need to take into account when using `Lazy<T>`?

I am trying to utilize `Lazy<T>` as often as I deem it appropriate, primarily to help reduce the memory footprint of our loaded, but inactive plugins.

Comment: I've just started using Lazy<T>, and find that it's often indicative of bad design; or laziness on the part of the programmer. Also, one disadvantage is that you have to be more vigilant with scoped up variables, and create proper closures.

Comment: @Gleno Why exactly is this programmer's laziness?

Comment: @Gleno, Anton: And more importantly, why is it bad? I always teach in my programming classes that laziness is an important virtue in programmers.

Comment: I'm surely for laziness as well, but sometimes it might be easier to do a Lazy evaluation than thinking through which exact resource will be used. In that case, opportunities to understand, simplify and prettify your own code will be missed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll expand a bit on my comment, which reads:

> I've just started using Lazy, and find that it's often indicative
>   of bad design; or laziness on the part of the programmer. Also, one
>   disadvantage is that you have to be more vigilant with scoped up
>   variables, and create proper closures.

For example, I've used `Lazy<T>` to create the pages the user can see in my (*sessionless*) MVC app. It's a guiding wizard, so the user might want to go to a random *previous* step. When the handshake is made, an array of `Lazy<Page>` objects is crated, and if the user specifies as step, that exact page is evaluated. I find it delivers good performance, but there are some aspects to it that I don't like, for example many of my `foreach` constructs now look like this:

```
foreach(var something in somethings){
     var somethingClosure = something;
     list.Add(new Lazy<Page>(() => new Page(somethingClosure));
}
```

I.e. you have to deal with the problem of closures very proactively. Otherwise I don't think it's such a bad performance hit to store a lambda and evaluate it when needed.

On the other hand this might be indicative that the programmer is being a `Lazy<Programmer>`, in the sense that you'd prefer not thinking through your program now, and instead let the proper logic evaluate when needed, as with example in my case - instead of building that array, I could just figure out just what that specific requested page would be; but I chose to be lazy, and do an all in approach.

**EDIT**

It occurs to me that `Lazy<T>` also has a few peculiars when working with concurrency. For example there's a `ThreadLocal<T>` for some scenarios, and several flag configurations for your particular multi-threaded scenario. You can read more on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx).

Comment: That's not a problem of `Lazy<T>` per se. Rather, it's how you use it.

Comment: @Anton, yes; and my conjecture is that Lazy<> is *sometimes* problematic in giving you the option of not looking for a better solution. Given that option you might settle for something that just works.

Comment: @Fuji, let's put it this way - the worst that can happen is that you suddenly would have to evaluate all your Lazy objects because of change in spec, or face a major rewrite. Can you live with that?

Comment: +1 for `var somethingClosure = something;` I've been looking for something to call my closures... Oh I'm kicking myself.

Comment: Note that in C# 5.0 (VS2012), the current iteration value is used in the closure by default... you no longer have the icky "extra local for the closure" problem.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh678682(v=vs.110).aspx for details.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, you should always have a reason for choosing Lazy. There are several alternatives depending on the use case and there are definitely cases where this structure is appropriate. But don't use it just because it's cool.

For example I don't get the point in the page selection example in one of the other answers. Using a list of Lazy for selecting a single element can be well done with a list or dictionary of delegates directly without using Lazy or with a simple switch statement.

So the most obvious alternatives are

- direct instantiation for cheap data structures or structures that are anyway needed
- delegates for things that are needed zero to few times in some algorithm
- some caching structure for items that should free the memory when not being used for some time
- some kind of "future" structure like Task that already may start initializing asynchronously before actual usage consuming idle CPU time in cases where the probability is quite high that the structure will be required later on

In contrast to that, Lazy is often suitable when

- computationally intense data structures
- are needed zero to many times in some algorithm where the zero case has a significant probability
- and the data is local to some method or class and can be garbage collected when not in use any more or the data should be kept in memory for the whole program's runtime

Answer (score 7):

Here's not quite a negative aspect, but a gotcha for lazy people :).

Lazy initializers are like static initializers. They get run **once**. If an exception is thrown, the exception is cached and subsequent calls to .Value would throw the same exception. This is by design and is mentioned in the docs ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329.aspx:

> Exceptions that are thrown by valueFactory are cached.

Hence, code as below will never return a value:

```
bool firstTime = true;
Lazy<int> lazyInt = new Lazy<int>(() =>
{
    if (firstTime)
    {
        firstTime = false;
        throw new Exception("Always throws exception the very first time.");
    }

    return 21;
});

int? val = null;
while (val == null)
{
    try
    {
        val = lazyInt.Value;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thilak. This is interesting. I did no clue that exceptions was cached like this.

Comment: @Fuji This is why the MEF team added ExportFactory and ExportLifetimeContext in MEF 2. Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/17/exportfactory-amp-lt-t-amp-gt-in-mef-2-alok.aspx

Comment: I think I need to go back and revise some of my MEF code now. ;)

Comment: This is only true some of the time: the behavior of exception caching depends on the publication method.

Comment: Consider using `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` if you want to avoid exception caching - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092

Answer (score 6):

I've come to use `Lazy<T>` mainly because of it's concurrency capabilities while loading resources from database. Thus I got rid of lock objects and arguable locking patterns.
In my case `ConcurrentDictionary` + `Lazy` as a value made my day, thanks to @Reed Copsey and his [blog post](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/)

> This looks like the following.  Instead of calling:
>
> ```
> MyValue value = dictionary.GetOrAdd(
>                              key, 
>                              () => new MyValue(key));
> ```
>
> We would instead use a ConcurrentDictionary>, and
>   write:
>
> ```
> MyValue value = dictionary.GetOrAdd(
>                              key, 
>                              () => new Lazy<MyValue>(
>                                  () => new MyValue(key)))
>                           .Value;
> ```

No downsides of `Lazy<T>` noticed so far.

Comment: That is pretty sweet. I have unfortunately been a bit too active today and ran out of votes, so I cannot up-vote your answer. ;*(

Answer (score 4):

As with anything, `Lazy<T>` can be used for good or for evil, hence a disadvantage: when used inappropriately, it can cause confusion and frustration. However, lazy initialization pattern has been around for years, and now that .NET BCL has an implementation developers don't need to reinvent the wheel yet again. What's more, [MEF loves Lazy](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/06/mef-or-managed-extensibility-framework.html).

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean with *"throughout my application"*?

I think it should only be used when you're not sure if the value will be used or not, which may only be the case with optional parameters that take a long time to compute. This could include complex calculations, file-handling, Webservices, database access and so on.

On the other hand, why use `Lazy` here? In most cases you can simply call a method instead of `lazy.Value` and it makes no difference anyway. BUT it's more simple and obvious to the programmer what's happening in this situation without `Lazy`.

One obvious upside may be already implemented caching of the value, but I don't think this is such a big advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy is used to preserve resources while not really needed. This pattern is pretty good but implementation can be useless.

Bigger the resource is, usefull is this pattern.

A disavantage to use Lazy class is the non transparency of usage. Indeed, you have to maintain everywhere an additional indirection (.Value).
When you just need an instance of real type, it is forced to load even if you dont need to use it directly.

Lazy is for lazy developpement gaining productivity but this gain can be lost by high usage.

If you have a real transparent implementation (using proxy pattern for exemple) it get rid of disavantage and it can be very usefull in many case.

Concurrency must be consider in an other aspect and not implemented by default in your type. It must be included only in client code or type helpers for this concept.