# Why use Lazy<T> instead of static factory class for singletons?

Tags: c#, singleton

Before I found the `Lazy<T>` type, I was using the following pattern for implementing global singletons:

```
class DataModel
{
    public static XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get { return SerializerFactory.instance; }
    }

    static class SerializerFactory
    {
        internal static readonly XmlSerializer instance =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataModel));
    }    
}
```

This pattern provides the following advantages:

1. Type initialization is lazy.
2. Type initialization is thread-safe.
3. Singleton access is simply a direct field access with no method calls.

Recently I've come across a lot of posts suggesting `Lazy<T>` for implementing similar singleton access patterns. Is there any benefit that `Lazy<T>` (or `LazyInitializer`) would bring to this implementation?

Comment: I would think that is only beneficial if constructing those instances is costly (time, IO, memory wise) and it's use is not immediately expected at startup. But as always: measure first, then decide based on evidence.

Comment: @rene I think that's correct for the Lazy Pattern in general. I read the OP more like wanting to know if it is beneficial to use `Lazy<T>` over an explicitly coded Holder Pattern to achieve a Lazy Singleton.

Comment: @rene Agreed. The question was more general, assuming situations in which this analysis has already been performed.

Comment: Both approaches work, but the danger with your approach is that it is necessary to make the `instance` a readonly field rather than a property - if someone changes it to use a property, it may no longer work correctly in all cases. The implementation is based on knowledge about some subtle details of static type initialization, including the effect that the `beforefieldinit` flag has on a type. Using `Lazy<T>` requires no such low-level knowledge.

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's article on implementing a singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This is **not** a singleton! It is a lazily instantiated static readonly property (of the class DataModel).

Comment: @Fildor what is your definition of a singleton, and how does this pattern differ from it?

Comment: Both default `Lazy` and the above singleton approach will cache the exception - consider using `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest you use **neither** of your options for a singleton in 90% of cases. I would instead use an IoC container (e.g. Autofac), register the class as a singleton with the container and inject it as per normal. _Thus making unit testing easier._

Comment: "what is your definition of a singleton" - [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) : "_... the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object_" - You *can* have more than one instance of `XmlSerializer` thus it is not a singleton. The instance returned from any DataModel object will be the same, that's all.

Comment: @Fildor fair enough, I agree the `XmlSerializer` class is itself not a singleton. The specific example in this case is more of a shared type cache. However many of the concerns are shared with the singleton pattern. The example was meant more as a simple illustration of the more general problem.

Comment: "However many of the concerns are shared with the singleton pattern." I agree with that.

Answer (score 13):

**Readability**

This is how your code would look like when implemented with `Lazy<T>`:

```
class DataModel
{
    private static readonly Lazy<XmlSerializer> lazySerializer = 
       new Lazy<XmlSerializer>(() => new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataModel)));

    public static XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get { return lazySerializer.Value; }
    }
}
```

1. You need less boilerplate code (no inner class),
2. the purpose of your code is *immediately obvious* to everyone reading it,
3. it is *much easier* to verify that the code is correct and thread-safe (no knowledge of subtle type initialization details required, a look at [`Lazy<T>`'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) suffices),
4. people reading your code won't wonder why you reinvented the wheel and whether there might be some subtle difference to the built-in feature.

Comment: You and OP are missing `private` parameterless constructor. With expression syntax getter is 1 liner.

Comment: Maybe this is true for people who are familiar with `Lazy<T>` but when I first saw code like this, its purpose was not immediately obvious. Specifically, you need to know the semantics of the `Lazy<T>` class, whereas the pattern I suggested uses purely language constructs.

Comment: @glopes In the pattern you use, do you know why `instance` must be a readonly field and not a property? Do you think that requirement is clear?

Comment: @Sinatr: I know, but since expression syntax could be used in the OPs case as well, I thought that it was unfair to use it in my example.

Comment: @glopes: True, the name `Lazy` heavily implies that this might have something to do with lazy initialization.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, and I agree that requirement may not be immediately obvious. However, when using a language I find it very important to know exactly what to expect from each keyword/pattern I use, so this code can also be a good learning experience for readers.

Comment: Singletons are good to be lazy. You get control when to initialize them too, static initialization is meh...

Comment: @Sinatr `Lazy<T>` assumes initialization on first access, which are exactly the same assumptions of the pattern I suggested.

Comment: @glopes Well I think we'll just have to agree to disagree about the concept that using patterns that assume arcane knowledge about the language is a good thing. In a learning context, maybe - but in production code, not so much... :)

Comment: @Sinatr the pattern I suggested also does not require `private` parameterless constructor because the factory class has been marked `static`.

Comment: @glopes, `DataModel` need `private` constructor, otherwise `new DataModel()` somewhere is possible, not really a singleton.

Comment: @Sinatr the serializer is the singleton, not `DataModel`. However, I was actually missing the `static` qualifier on the `Serializer` property, which I now fixed.

Comment: @Sinatr the `XmlSerializer` for `DataModel` is only constructed once, and can be reused everytime someone needs to serialize/deserialize an instance of `DataModel`.

Comment: @glopes Isn't that more of a lazily instantiated static member than a "singleton" then?

Comment: @Fildor you can call it a lazily initialized singleton, but technically it is still just a singleton from the API consumer's point of view.

Comment: `whereas the pattern I suggested uses purely language constructs` Do you use LINQ @glopes ? If so, why? Since it requires understanding more than purely language constructs (like for loops)... You use it because it **better expresses intent**. _Also, `Lazy` is useful for things **other** than singletons. So, the average developer is going to have to understand it **anyway**._

Comment: @mjwills I never said I don't use anything other than purely language constructs. I only indicated that I prefer to learn the language constructs in detail first before learning other constructs built on top of the language.

Comment: That is a fair approach @glopes . Just be aware that that approach is optimising for you, and perhaps not for **every** developer. **I**, for example, find the Lazy solution much clearer and simpler to read since it expresses intent so clearly (although, as in my comment on your question I would use IoC rather than `Lazy`).

Answer (score 4):

`Lazy<T>` is much more expressive. It is immediately clear that the value utilizes deferred initialization.

For example I use it in situations when the intialization of some resource is too heavy to put in the constructor and I don't want the API-consumer to call some explicit Initialize routine.