# Implement IDisposable on C# Volatile Objects

Tags: c#, class, singleton, volatile, idisposable

I'm using the singleton design pattern for my Business Layer and Data Access Layer classes in C#.

My Class looks as below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;

public class CabBookingDao: IDisposable
{
    private static volatile CabBookingDao _instance;
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

    private readonly DatabaseProviderFactory _factory;
    private readonly Database _db;
}

public static CabBookingDao Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
               if (_instance == null)
                 _instance = new CabBookingDao();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}

private CabBookingDao()
{
    _factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
    _db = _factory.Create("MyDbContext");
}

public void Dispose()
{
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Here, I'm trying to Implement IDisposable for this class and I'm getting Warning from VS Code Analyzer like:

> CA1063    Implement IDisposable correctly Provide an overridable
>   implementation of Dispose(bool) on 'CabBookingDao' or mark the type as
>   sealed. A call to Dispose(false) should only clean up native
>   resources. A call to Dispose(true) should clean up both managed and
>   native resources  CabBookingDao.cs

By this warning, I understood that I suppose to create a method as below:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        // free managed resources
    }
    // free native resources if there are any.
}
```

But, I'm confused about what objects do I need to dispose here? If I dispose **_instance**, will it affect the Singleton behavior?

Comment: `But, I'm confused about what objects do I need to dispose here?` Non-static members of the object that aren't shared with other objects.

Comment: Do you mean, In my case, `_factory` and `_db`?

Comment: _Probably_, yes. It depends on a number of factors. For example, you may have a IoC container, which _may_ mean you don't need the `Dispose` at all (since the container will handle it for you). But my first comment is a reasonable "general rule".

Comment: To be clear, I wouldn't use your `lock` technique - I'd just use `Lazy` instead (well technically I'd use https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092).

Comment: @55SK55 I suggest dropping the double-check lazy initialization pattern, it's nearly impossible to deal right with volatile fields. There are some well-tested framework constructions for this purpose: [Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) or [LazyInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'd suggest something like `private static Lazy<CabBookingDao> _instance = new Lazy<CabBookingDao>(() => new CabBookingDao());` Again, I'd use `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` instead to be safer though - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529533/system-lazyt-with-different-thread-safety-mode/42567351#42567351 .

Comment: If you shut it down and recreate it's **not** a singleton, it's just an object.  You don't implement a disposable singleton.  Singletons go out of scope automatically when the `AppDomain` is shutdown (which happens to be when you program is terminating) and typically you only have **one** unless you are making child `AppDomain`s