# Wrap RabbitMQ Connection in a singleton class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, rabbitmq, singleton

I have read that when I use RabbitMQ the best practice is to use one connection per process, so I would like to create a singleton class for the rabbitmq connection. I would like to use the Lazy version of Singleton from:
[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton#lazy)

I write this class:

```
public class RabbitConnection
{
    private static readonly Lazy<RabbitConnection>  Lazy = new Lazy<RabbitConnection>(() => new RabbitConnection());

    private RabbitConnection()
    {
        IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = "127.0.0.1",
            Port = 5672,
            UserName = "Username",
            Password = "********"
        };

        Connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
    }

    public static RabbitConnection Instance
    {
        get { return Lazy.Value; }
    }

    public IConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

And use this like:

```
var channel = RabbitConnection.Instance.Connection.CreateModel();
channel.QueueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null);
....
```

Is this implementation right or wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: `Lazy` (as used in your code, with the default `LazyThreadSafetyMode`) is safe to use **if you can be 100% sure the constructor will not throw an exception**. Since it can be hard to know that sometimes (without a thorough code analysis), I use `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read that when I use RabbitMQ the best practice is to use one
> connection per process

No, this is not correct. You should use as many connections as your use-case demands and determine connection / channel count by using benchmarks of your expected workload.

Comment: I wonder if the OP is referring to "The best practice is to reuse connections and multiplex a connection between threads with channels. You should ideally only have one connection per process, and then use a channel per thread in your application." from https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html.