# What's the difference between Lazy and Func?

Tags: c#, .net

In factory class, constant service is being used to get data from a microservice. I wanted **lazy initialization** of the service. I found two ways for that and both are working.

**using Func**

```
public class ClientFactory: IClientFactory
{
    private readonly Func<IConstantService> _constants;

    public ClientFactory(Func<IConstantService> constants)
    {
        _constants = constants;
    }

    public Client GetClient()
    {
        return new Client(_constants().Uri);
    }
}
```

**using Lazy**

```
public class ClientFactory: IClientFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<IConstantService> _constants;

    public ClientFactory(Lazy<IConstantService> constants)
    {
        _constants = constants;
    }

    public Client GetClient()
    {
        return new Client(_constants.Value.Uri);
    }
}
```

**what's the difference?**

Comment: `Lazy<T>` is thread safe; it can be helpful if `_constants().Uri`  is not

Comment: There is no better, there is only completely different. `Lazy<T>` is specifically for the *thread-safe* lazy loading of *resources*

Comment: Please define "better". It can be better in terms of thread safety, or cpu usage, memory consumption, execution speed, or code readability. For the latter, I would say that `Lazy` conveys the intention much better than `Func` - and therefor you should use `Lazy`. for thread safety you should use `Lazy` (See Demitry's comment). For cpu, memory or speed I don't know. You will need to [race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *fundamental* difference between `Func` and `Lazy` is that `Func` is for creating **things** (i.e. 0+) while `Lazy` is for creating **a thing** (singular, or 0-1).

Every time you invoke a `Func` you may potentially get a new value (the 'may' is because depending on what exactly the `Func` does - it might return the same value, or it might not).

The `Lazy` will (by default) give you the same value **repeatedly**. Even if multiple threads ask for the value of the `Lazy`, they'll all (by default) get the same object. The `Lazy` also (by default) suffers from [exception caching](https://theburningmonk.com/2013/04/be-lazy-but-be-ware-of-initialization-exception/), which the `Func` doesn't.

If you want `Lazy` without exception caching, [`LazyWithNoExceptionCaching`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092) may be of interest. This is what I use day to day.

A common place to use `Func` rather than `Lazy`, as an example, is inside a singleton. That way the singleton can `new` up multiple instances of another type as needed. If it used a `Lazy` it would only have a single instance of that other type.

*Above, I keep saying **by default**. This is because `Lazy` has [different modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode?view=netframework-4.8). My comments are all regarding `ExecutionAndPublication` - the default behaviour.*