# Lazy Initialization (Lazy<T>) or Property with a Backing Field

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

According to Microsoft,

> Lazy initialization of an object means that its creation is deferred
> until it is first used. (For this topic, the terms lazy initialization
> and lazy instantiation are synonymous.) Lazy initialization is
> primarily used to improve performance, avoid wasteful computation, and
> reduce program memory requirements.

Suppose I have a `Product` class and a `Category` class, and the relationship is one-to-many, which means that a Product object holds a Category object, and a Category object holds a collection of Product objects.

This is the code of the Product class:

```
class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code for the Category class:

```
class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
```

In this scenario, the Product objects of the Category object is not always needed, so it does not always need to be always initialized. So, this is what I did:

```
class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> products;
    public ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            if (products == null)
            {
                // retrieves the products from the database and stores it in field: products
            }
            return products;
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this, the Products is retrieved once and only when it is asked for right? Then, I read about Lazy Initialization, and I draft my Category class like so:

```
class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> products;
    public Lazy<ICollection<Product>> Products => new Lazy<ICollection<Product>>(() => GetProductsByCategoryID(this.CategoryID));

    public ICollection<Product> GetProductsByCategoryID(int categoryID)
    {
        // retrieves the products from the database
    }
}
```

My questions are, how are these two implementations different? Does the lazy initialization provides a better performance or uses less memory?

Comment: The main benefit of `Lazy` in that instance is that if two threads ask for the value at the same time, `GetProductsByCategoryID` will be called only once. The main downside is that if `GetProductsByCategoryID` throws an exception then all future requests will see that exception (which your first code block likely won't suffer from). I personally would use `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092 .

Comment: In either case, you are potentially breeding bad practice since you are not using async/await and you are blocking threads.  You might want to think through what it would take to add async/await and then see how that determines your approach.

Comment: @DavidL I will go though it. Does using async/await helps with memory allocations and computation as well?

Comment: No, it helps with threading throughput for I/O-bound calls.  Since you are using Lazy (presumably to reduce concurrent threads requesting the same data), it makes sense to also eliminate blocked threads during I/O waits.