If I populate a dictionary and assign it to a field - can I guarantee the field will not contain a half populated dictionary?
In the below code, I populate the contents of the dictionary then assign it to Data. As such, my mental expectation is that Data will contain either null or a Dictionary with two elements in it.
But is that a valid expectation?
I know that writes can be reordered. And the simple fix, presumably, would be to add volatile to Data. But is that needed? Or is the original code guaranteed "safe" (safe in the sense that I can be 100% confident that Data will never contain a Dictionary that has < 2 elements in it).
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<int, int> Data = null;
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bob = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        bob.Add(1, 1);
        bob.Add(2, 2);
        
        Data = bob;

        // Note that there be no further mutation of `bob` or `Data` after this.

        // Imagine there is a separate thread reading the contents of `Data`
    }
}

I am not even super confident of the volatile suggestion in light of the wisdom of Skeet and Lippert ("Frankly, I discourage you from ever making a volatile field.").

i know errors cannot happen on an x86_64 machine because it doesn't reorder writes, but ARM can ... so you better make Data volatile if you intend on running this on an ARM machine, and the other thread was spawned before the dictionary was created.

@mjwills: https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/ - x86-64 has acquire and release for free; any load syncs-with the store that produced the value it loaded, so later loads see all earlier stores from the writer thread.  This is not the case on weakly-ordered ISAs like ARM and AArch64: you need C# volatile or some other way to do a release store and an acquire load.

C#'s volatile is sufficient for this use-case: if the other thread sees Data as non-null, it can safely read the entries you assigned.  Writing non-trivial lock-free code is hard, though.  What should the other thread do if it does see null?  What if you want to add further entries while multiple threads are reading or writing?  Basically they mean that as a blanket recommendation not to write lock-free code.  They're not saying that volatile is the wrong choice if you are!  (But you're not the first to misread it that way; I hate it when people phrase it that way.)

@PeterCordes What should the other thread do if it does see null? The real code will, if it sees null, go and populate a new dictionary and then assign it to Data (basically the same code you see in Main). The basis for my question was effectively "is that safe to do?" and the answer seems to be "no". Well, it will be fine for now since we are running on Intel. But it isn't safe in general. What if you want to add further entries while multiple threads are reading or writing? That won't be an issue here - // Note that there be no further mutation of boborData after this

@PeterCordes I suspect the replacement I will suggest they use is basically Lazy (well, LazyWithNoExceptionCaching - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092). Since it solves the issue and is a better match for what the original code is trying to achieve (basically a cache which never changes and is loaded on demand).

Sounds like your case is fairly simple, then.  I meant those more as an example of the kinds of complexity you can get into with lock-free programming, as reasons why people might say things like "never use volatile".

I typically use a static constructor for cases like this. (And I use them a lot)

Yeah a static constructor could be useful, they will be safe in a similar way to Lazy / LazyWithNoExceptionCaching.

Be cautious when using a static constructor for this purpose; the fact that a static constructor takes out a hidden lock is a double-edged sword. Usually it does the right thing but if you try to get too fancy you can end up in a deadlock even with no lock statements in your program! https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/

Another thing that can go wrong with overly fancy static constructors is the accidental introduction of a type initializer circular dependency.  It's especially nasty in that such a bug will silently disrupt your programs' invariants.  Such bugs tend to hide themselves a bit more than deadlocks.


I know that writes can be reordered. And the simple fix, presumably, would be to add volatile to Data. But is that needed?

Yes, it is definitely needed. Without the volatile the compiler/Jitter/processor might reorder the instructions of the program in a way that the Data might point for a brief period of time to a partially initialized Dictionary<K,V> object. The behavior of a partially initialized object is undefined. It might contain less than 2 elements, it might throw exceptions, whatever. Or it might work correctly because no reordering actually happened. If you want to be responsible and leave nothing to chance, you should definitely declare the Data as volatile, so that any possibility of reordering is prevented.
A detailed explanation about why the volatile is needed in lazy-initialization scenarios, can be found in this 2013 article by Igor Ostrovsky:

The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice, Part 2

